# Pipe shell output to svn del command?

Tags: shell, svn

I have a rather complicated deploy setup for our Drupal site that is a combination of CVS and SVN. We use CVS to get the newest versions of modules, and we deploy with SVN. Unfortunately, when CVS updates remove files, Subversions complains because they weren't removed in SVN. I am trying to do some shell scripting and Perl to run an `svn rm` command on all these files that have already been deleted from the filesystem, but I have not gotten far. What I have so far is this:

```
svn st | grep !
```

This outputs a list of all the files deleted from the filesystem like so:

```
!       panels_views/panels_views.info
!       panels_views/panels_views.admin.inc
!       contexts/term.inc
!       contexts/vocabulary.inc
!       contexts/terms.inc
!       contexts/node_edit_form.inc
!       contexts/user.inc
!       contexts/node_add_form.inc
!       contexts/node.inc
etc. . .
```

However, I want to somehow run an `svn del` on each of these lines. How can I get this output into my Perl script, or alternatively, how can I run `svn del` on each of these lines?

**Edit:** The exact command I used, with some help from all, was

```
svn st | grep ^! | cut -c 9- | xargs svn del
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using `xargs`, like this:

```
svn st | grep ^! | cut -f2 | xargs svn rm
```

The `xargs` command takes lines on its standard input, and turns them around and uses those lines as command line parameters on the `svn rm`. By default, `xargs` uses multiple lines with each invocation of its command, which in the case of `svm rm` is fine.

You may also have to experiment with the `cut` command to get it just right. By default, `cut` uses a tab as a delimiter and Subversion may output spaces there. In that case, you may have to use `cut -d' ' -f6` or something.

As always when building such a command pipeline, run portions at a time to make sure things look right. So run everything up to the `cut` command to ensure that you have the list of file names you expect, *before* running it again with `"| xargs svn rm"` on the end.

Comment: I would change `grep !` to `grep ^!` to ensure that we don't accidentally kill files that happen to have exclamation points in their path.

Comment: Wonderful, I had no idea about cut or xargs. I knew Perl was not the simplest way, but I have a bit of familiarity with.

Answer (score 1):

```
svn st | egrep ^! | cut -b 9- | xargs svn del
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as an alternative to the ones above, I'd use something like:

```
svn st | awk '$1=="!"{print $2}' | xargs svn del
```

I find awk's pattern-matching language very handy for tasks like this.